# Error Signing Terms of Service issue of Safe Wallet

Tags: safe-core

When I connect to a dApp, I want to sign to accept the terms of service, but I get an error in Safe Wallet saying 'something went wrong' and I cannot sign. Can you check it why? What should I do for this issue?

Comment: Please use proper channels for reporting bugs. This is not a developer question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question relates to Safe{Wallet}, not Safe{Core}. Feel free to reach out to https://help.safe.global for topics related to our UI!

Hope it helps,
Louis